# Mysql query not working for me Codeigniter Php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, join

I am working with mysql with codeigniter, hHere is my table structure:

Table A:

```
id(doctorid)            name    
-----------------------------
1                       abc
2                       xyz
3                       ahd
4                       djd
```

Table B:

```
id          doctor_id       type
-------------------------------------
1           1               Nuter
2           3               Spay
```

Now I want to get all records of doctor with count of type, I want the following result:

```
id          name        Nuter     Spay
---------------------------------------
1           abc         1         0
2           xyz         0         Spay
```

I tried with following code but not working for me, how can I do this ?

```
$this->db->select('A.*');
$this->db->from('A');
$this->db->join('B', 'B.doctor_id = (SELECT COUNT(Type) FROM B )');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: The join condition seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$this->db->select('A.*,B.type');
$this->db->from('A');
$this->db->join('B', 'B.doctor_id = A.id');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are looking for conditional aggregation.

In pure SQL, the query should look like:

```
SELECT
    A.id,
    A.name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN B.type = 'Nuter' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Nuter,
    SUM(CASE WHEN B.type = 'Spay' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Spay
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON B.doctor_id = A.id
GROUP BY A.id, A.name
```

If you have a 1-1 relationship between tables A and B instead of 1-N (as your sample data suggests), then this can be simplified as:

```
SELECT
    A.id,
    A.name,
    CASE WHEN B.type = 'Nuter' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Nuter,
    CASE WHEN B.type = 'Spay' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Spay
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON B.doctor_id = A.id
```

Try:

```
$this->db->select(
    "A.id,
    A.name,
    CASE WHEN B.type = 'Nuter' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Nuter,
    CASE WHEN B.type = 'Spay' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Spay"
);
$this->db->from('A');
$this->db->join('B', 'B.doctor_id = A.id');
$query = $this->db->get();
```